Astro and React island; react-hook-form and zod don't validate the input field
I was trying to build a Contact Form component with Shadcn UI (using React-hook-form and Zod)
However, the problem was
[vite] The requested module 'react-hook-form' does not provide an export named 'FieldValues'
I edited astro.config.mjs and put this code and it worked well. It showed the component
export default defineConfig({
  //...
  vite: {
    ssr: {
      noExternal: ['react-hook-form'],
    },
  },
});


In ContactPage.astro
<ContactForm client:load />

Here is the error and it doesn't validate the input field.
[astro-island] SyntaxError: The requested module doesn't provide an export named: 'FieldPath'
Any suggestion please. Did I fix incorrectly by editing ssr.noExternal?

It may be that in Form.tsx the FieldValues type definition has to be imported with a type-only import. Did you check that?
